# Cannot load font el-icon in vuejs + spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, vue.js

I am doing my project with spring boot + vuejs(element-ui) and deploy it in a server without internet.

I have an issue: **My website cannot load icon from el-icon when I build war file to run in tomcat but it works with jar file**

[image]

Please help me to resolve it.

This is pom file

```html
    <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${frontend-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <workingDirectory>src/main/frontend</workingDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install node and yarn</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-yarn</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <nodeVersion>${nodejs.version}</nodeVersion>
                            <yarnVersion>v1.22.4</yarnVersion>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>yarn install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>yarn</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>install</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>yarn build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>yarn</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>build</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-frontend</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/classes/resources/</outputDirectory>
                            <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/frontend/dist</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>static/</include>
                                        <include>index.html</include>
                                        <include>favicon.ico</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

and this is vue.config.js file

```js
'use strict'
const path = require('path')
const defaultSettings = require('./src/settings.js')

function resolve(dir) {
  return path.join(__dirname, dir)
}

const name = defaultSettings.title || 'Interconnect System' // page title

// If your port is set to 80,
// use administrator privileges to execute the command line.
// For example, Mac: sudo npm run
// You can change the port by the following method:
// port = 9527 npm run dev OR npm run dev --port = 9527
//const port = process.env.port || process.env.npm_config_port || 9527 // dev port

// All configuration item explanations can be find in https://cli.vuejs.org/config/
module.exports = {
    publicPath: '/InterconnectSystem',
    devServer: {
      proxy: {
        '/InterconnectSystem': {
          target: '/',
          ws: true,
          changeOrigin: true
        }
      }
    },
    lintOnSave: false,
    outputDir: 'dist',
    assetsDir: 'static',
    // resolve: {
    //   alias: {
    //     '@': resolve('src')
    //   }
    // },
  chainWebpack(config) {
    // it can improve the speed of the first screen, it is recommended to turn on preload
    // it can improve the speed of the first screen, it is recommended to turn on preload
    config.plugin('preload').tap(() => [
      {
        rel: 'preload',
        // to ignore runtime.js
        // https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/dev/packages/@vue/cli-service/lib/config/app.js#L171
        fileBlacklist: [/\.map$/, /hot-update\.js$/, /runtime\..*\.js$/],
        include: 'initial'
      }
    ])
  
    // when there are many pages, it will cause too many meaningless requests
    config.plugins.delete('prefetch')
  
    // set svg-sprite-loader
    config.module
      .rule('svg')
      .exclude.add(resolve('src/icons'))
      .end()
    config.module
      .rule('icons')
      .test(/\.svg$/)
      .include.add(resolve('src/icons'))
      .end()
      .use('svg-sprite-loader')
      .loader('svg-sprite-loader')
      .options({
        symbolId: 'icon-[name]'
      })
      .end()
  
    config
      .when(process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development',
        config => {
          config
            .plugin('ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin')
            .after('html')
            .use('script-ext-html-webpack-plugin', [{
            // `runtime` must same as runtimeChunk name. default is `runtime`
              inline: /runtime\..*\.js$/
            }])
            .end()
          config
            .optimization.splitChunks({
              chunks: 'all',
              cacheGroups: {
                libs: {
                  name: 'chunk-libs',
                  test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                  priority: 10,
                  chunks: 'initial' // only package third parties that are initially dependent
                },
                elementUI: {
                  name: 'chunk-elementUI', // split elementUI into a single package
                  priority: 20, // the weight needs to be larger than libs and app or it will be packaged into libs or app
                  test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]_?element-ui(.*)/ // in order to adapt to cnpm
                },
                commons: {
                  name: 'chunk-commons',
                  test: resolve('src/components'), // can customize your rules
                  minChunks: 3, //  minimum common number
                  priority: 5,
                  reuseExistingChunk: true
                }
              }
            })
          // https:// webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimizationruntimechunk
          config.optimization.runtimeChunk('single')
        }
      )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that Maven was filtering the font files and corrupting them.

```
<resource>
    <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
</resource>
```

The fix was to make the following changes to the pom.xml

```
<resource>
    <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
    <excludes>
        <exclude>static/fonts/**</exclude>
    </excludes>
</resource>

<resource>
    <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>false</filtering>
    <includes>
        <include>static/fonts/**</include>
    </includes>
</resource>
```

This change allows for the fonts to not be filtered during packaging.

Hope this helps for anyone.